# Condition SQL Join

Tags: sql, join

We have a table of users where most have a school number attached. I've then used an Inner Join to join the school's table to get the name of the school. Some users don't have a school number so there is a NULL value - which means that none of their data is appearing. Is there a way I can do a conditional join dependent on the schoolid field?

Users Table:

```
Name | Schoolid
-----|---------
John | 27
Fred | 49
Sam  | NULL
```

School Table:

```
Schoolid  | Schoolname
----------|-----------
27        | John's School
49        | Fred's School
```

When the tables are Joined on the Schoolid the results are

```
Name | Schoolname
-----|-----------
John | John's School
Fred | Fred's School
```

Ideally I would like the results to look like this:

```
Name | Schoolname
-----|-----------
John | John's School
Fred | Fred's School
Sam  | NULL
```

Can anybody help? Is it something simple and I'm just being an idiot?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: why `OUTER`? I'd go with just `left join`, is this ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for an outer join.

E.g.

```
select * from Users left outer join School on Users.Schoolid = School.Schoolid
```

[Microsoft has an article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) with some examples that may make it more clear, even if you're using a different SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN School s ON u.Schoolid = s.Schoolid
```

Or even.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users u
FULL OUTER JOIN School s ON u.Schoolid = s.Schoolid
```

Comment: why `full`? OP doesn't request for school names without students in it.